# If the Sun shrunk to the diameter of the earth, would Earth be habitable?

Tags: astrophysics, density, sun

I was thinking about the sun. What if it shrunk in diameter to the size of the Earth? It wouldn't change the gravity much. But would it change the heat? If so, would the earth become uninhabitable?

My hypothesis is no because it just gets smaller and has the same mass. But the sun would become invisible.

Answer (score 3):

The size of a star is determined by its amss and the balance between of gravity and the plasma and radiation pressure. It's imopossible to change the star's size without changing its chemical composition and the reactions that happen inside.

A squeezed Sun wouldn't be able to stay at this small size on its own - the pressure inside would be too great. So unless you somehow were able to keep squeezing it to keep it's size at what you wnat, it would almost instantly explode. Whether that would end up with the destruction of the Sun or it regaining it's original size, I can't tell.

But if you somehow were able to keep external pressure on the Sun to keep it in its squeezed size, the temperature inside would rose, the nuclear reactions would happen faster, and the total energy radiated from the Sun would be much more than it is today. It would almost certainly make the Earth unhabitable.